# ng-class not adding has-error when error in input field

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to perform simple form validation. I'm using required and ng-minlength conditions on my fields and ng-messages to display the error messages. the error messages should display only when user access the input field. But I do not see any error messages appearing. When I examined using chrome developer tools, I found the classes on the input field are changing but the 'has-error' class is not being added on the other `div` elements that are checking for this condition.

[image] this is when the application got loaded.

[image] this is when I clicked the username field and left the field without giving any data. Please observe the classes of the elements marked in red boxes. I'm not getting any errors displayed. What might the issue be?

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCcIw.png) this is the ng-messages code snippet that i'm using

```html
<form role="form" name="userForm" novalidate class="container-fluid">
              <div class="margin-bottom" ng-class="{'has-error' : userExists.notAvailable , 'has-error': userForm.username.$touched && userForm.username.$invalid}">
                <label for="email">username</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="UserName" name="username" ng-blur="checkingUser($event)" ng-model="username" required ng-minlength="4">
                <div ng-messages='userExists'>
                   <div ng-message='error'>Error!</div>
                   <div class="form-group" ng-message='notAvailable' class="has-error">Username already exists. Please choose a different username!!</div>
               </div>

               <div class="help-block" ng-messages="userForm.username.$error" ng-show="userForm.username.$touched" ng-class="{'has-error': userForm.username.$touched && userForm.username.$invalid}">
                  <div class="form-group" ng-message='required' class="has-error">Username cannot be empty</div>
                  <div class="form-group" ng-message='minlength'>minimum 4 charcters</div>
              </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Could you post your code in text for easy reading?

Comment: Sorry to bother you but please also post your AngularJS code if you still have problem.

Comment: thanks a lot for trying to help me Soyokaze.. but unfortunately i cannot share that code..only so am trying my best to explain the issue using the generalized code version.

Comment: If my code doesn't work for you, there should be something wrong with you js code. Please ensure you injected ngMessage and other required ones.

Answer (score 0):

Edited after the source code is posted:

```
<div class="margin-bottom" ng-class="{'has-error' : userExists.notAvailable , 'has-error': userForm.username.$touched && userForm.username.$invalid}">
    <label for="email">username</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="UserName" name="username"  ng-blur="checkingUser($event)" ng-model="username" ng-required="true" ng-minlength="4">

    <div ng-messages='userExists'>
        <div ng-message='error'>Error!</div>
        <div class="form-group has-error" ng-message='notAvailable' >Username already exists. Please choose a different username!!</div>
    </div>

    <div ng-messages="userForm.username.$touched && userForm.username.$error" ng-class="{'has-error': userForm.username.$touched && userForm.username.$invalid}">
        <div class="form-group has-error" ng-message='required'>Username cannot be empty</div>
        <div class="form-group" ng-message='minlength'>minimum 4 charcters</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This works on my machine.

[image]

The message will be displayed **after you've submitted the form**.

Make sure you've added required dependency in your module to use ngMessage. If necessary, please post the AngularJS code as well.